# web3.py return from a get function in strange format

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3py

i'm developing a python app. This app is just to get data from the blockchain. In web3.js it all works good, but i need to do it in python (the client wants a python app). It all works almost good; The script does what it needs to do, but when calling the get function i get a strange output (using the get function on remix or web3.js whit a nodeJs api that i wrote works just perfect) :

```
D:\pytoh\b_get\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Alessandro/PycharmProjects/pytoh/b_get/bget.py
True
[(b'\xe9:=\xd87/\x98\x00\xe4\x89\xe3\x8eb[c\x9cj\xc4\xa3\xa2b\x1d\x9a\xf0%\x1d\xdaB\xb7\xd9\xc4\xe3', 
b'\xe9:=\xd87/\x98\x00\xe4\x89\xe3\x8eb[c\x9cj\xc4\xa3\xa2b\x1d\x9a\xf0%\x1d\xdaB\xb7\xd9\xc4\xe3')]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The output that i need is like this (i don't understand why the py output is like that):[0xe93a3dd8372f9800e489e38e625b639c6ac4a3a2621d9af0251dda42b7d9c4e3,0xe93a3dd8372f9800e489e38e625b639c6ac4a3a2621d9af0251dda42b7d9c4e3]

The python script is simple (i'm still writing it):

```
import json
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545'))
print(w3.isConnected())
with open("ABI.json") as f:
  info_json = json.load(f)
abi = info_json["output"]["abi"]

 address = "0x1305ef6377fe8cB7C6dD7Eb2B6cAD83A34fC7503"
 get = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi) 
 result=get.functions.getUser("0xe93a3dd8372f9800e489e38e
                       625b639c6ac4a3a2621d9af0251dda42b7d9c4e3").call()
 print(result)
```

And this is the smart contract that the client wrote:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.26;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract crud{
  address owner;
  constructor() public{
  owner = msg.sender;
}
modifier onlyOwner () {
   require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}
struct user{
    bytes32 hash_json;
    bytes32 hash_corso;
}
 mapping (bytes32 => user[]) public users;

 
 function setUser(bytes32 _hash, bytes32 _hash_json, bytes32 _hash_corso) onlyOwner  public {
     user memory usr;
     usr.hash_json=_hash_json;
     usr.hash_corso= _hash_corso;
     users[_hash].push(usr);
 }
 
 function getUser(bytes32 _hash) view public returns (user[] memory) {
     return users[_hash];
 }

 }
```

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is a byte array. When you print it, it converts control characters to hex but prints readable characters.

To get a full hex string, try this:

```
result = bytearray([22,32,7,67,14,87,90])  # for testing
hxstr = "".join(["{:02x}".format(v) for v in result])
print("0x"+hxstr)
```

Output

```
0x162007430e575a
```

Comment: Hi, ty for your answer, the code now works but i have another huge problem. the console shows and i don't know what to do:                                                                                                                                                  ` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alessandro/PycharmProjects/pytoh/b_get/bget.py", line 12, in <module>
    result=bytearray(get.functions.getUser("0xe93a3dd8372f9800e489e38e625b639c6ac4a3a2621d9af0251dda42b7d9c4e3").call())
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer '

Comment: You should not need `bytearray()` in your code. Just use `result=get.functions....`

Comment: sorry, i changed it but now it says this:                                                                   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alessandro/PycharmProjects/pytoh/b_get/bget.py", line 13, in <module>
    hxstr = "".join(["{:02x}".format(v) for v in result])
  File "C:/Users/Alessandro/PycharmProjects/pytoh/b_get/bget.py", line 13, in <listcomp>
    hxstr = "".join(["{:02x}".format(v) for v in result])
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__

Comment: I think `call()` is returning a tuple. Try using `....v in result[0][0]])` in the hxstr line.

Comment: Hi, i rewrote the smartcontract, and added ` ....v in result[0]) ` and now it works perfect ty <3